# How to remove inner div from create block in drupal 7

Tags: 7, blocks

Here, i struggling to remove inner div from create block in drupal 7.Here my working code with wrong result:

```
 <div class="ft_bottom">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-7">
<?php  if($page['footer_bottom_left']){ print render($page['footer_bottom_left']);} ?>
</div>
<div class="col-md-5">
  <?php  if($page['footer_bottom_left']){ print render($page['footer_bottom_right']);} ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I used `string_tags` before render it remove entire html tags. But i need to remove only block div and content div.Here my wrong result:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <div class="region region-footer-bottom-right">
    <div class="block block-block" id="block-block-5">
      <div class="content">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Plan du site</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Acessibilite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Mentions legales</a></li>
</ul>  </div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Correct format:

```
<div class="col-md-5">

        <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Plan du site</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Acessibilite</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Credits</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Mentions legales</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>
```

How to remove inner div from custom block in drupal 7.Kindly guide me..?

Comment: I feel like we need more information. Are you using a custom template file? A preprocess hook and adjustment for this specific block?

Comment: Yes i used custom template ! @AlexLaughnan and how to create custom function for changing block in template.php file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markup you require removing comes from one or more template files. While i have no idea what theme you are using, ill assume its one that hasn't overidden the default template files..

If you go and get the file modules/system/region.tpl.php and copy it to your theme folder you can remove the markup you do not require. e.g. delete `<div class="region region-footer-bottom-right">`

To get rid of the rest of the markup you will have to override the block template in the same fashion, to only remove the markup from 1 specific block you can use naming suggestions here https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656

note: Flush the caches for the theme to pick up the presence of any new template files.